# Change background color, without a new paragraph and across environments

Tags: color

`{\color }` can do that, but only for the color of text. I would want the same for the background. I have looked across many solutions, but they either can not go across environments (e.g. `colorbox`) or create new paragraphs (e.g. `framed`).

I just want to highlight arbitrary regions of text, without any other modification to them.

**EDIT:**
An example for gigi:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color,soul}
\sethlcolor{red}
\begin{document}


text \hl{
\begin{itemize}
        \item text
\end{itemize}
} text

\end{document}
```

It produces:

```
$ pdflatex a.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./a.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/soul/soul.sty) (./a.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)

! LaTeX Error: Environment {itemize} undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.12 }
       text
?
```

Answer (score 1):

The `soul` package can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color,soul}
\sethlcolor{red}
\begin{document}


text \hl{text} text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wrapping `itemize` with `hl` caused `LaTeX Error: Environment {itemize} undefined`.

Comment: @arataj Can you add a document to your question that shows the problem?

Comment: I added an example.